# Interactively set the positions of subplots using plt.subplot2grid

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter, subplot, interactive

in my experience, `plt.subplot2grid` can be very handy in setting custom layouts for subplots in a complex multi-panel figure (e.g. as in the image below). However, I must say setting the positions of the subplots using `plt.subplot2grid` can get very tedious, especially adjusting and re-adjusting the subplots can become very time consuming.

To make things easier, I wonder if there is any way to interactively set the subplots. I would imagine some tool that would look like this for example:
[image]

Using this "hypothetical" tool, one could first (1) intiate a grid (e.g. 14x20 as shown in the image above) then interactively (2) one could simply draw rectangles (black rectangle in the above image), and finally (3) close the interactive session to obtain the positions of the rectangles to create the subplots using `plt.subplot2grid`. For example, for the upper left rectangle in the above image, the based on the obtained positions, the subplot could create using this line of code `plt.subplot2grid(shape=[14,20],loc=[1,1],rowspan=6,colspan=4)`.

Ideally such a tool could be used in the jupyter notebook, but a non-jupyter based one could also do the trick.

I searched around but could not find any such tool.
I am a programmer, but I am not familiar with building interactive tools. So I haven't tried to develop such a tool myself.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I've seen that sounds like what you seek is [Pylustrator](https://pylustrator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The video at that link gives a good overview.

It doesn't run in a notebook because it uses a graphical user interface of it's own with some complex ability built in, but makes code that you can then use in a notebook later because you can remove the Pyustrator invoking code and use it anywhere.

If you want to try Pylustrator without installing anything on your own local machine, you can launch a session in a temporary remote linux desktop served via MyBInder [by clicking this link specifically](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/spyder-ide/spyder/master?urlpath=%2Fdesktop). Step through the directions [here](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/2342446eab163f8d71b93f8d5f0924c3) to use it, skipping the first step under 'Full Graphical User Interface/ Code Editor Demo' because if you use the link above you already have that.

---

This other answer where I used it might help you get a quick sense of it's abilities and/or plug-in better:

- [answer to 'How to increase the size of only one plot in subplots?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74072943/8508004)

Comment: Wow, Pylustrator looks cool! Thank you so much for suggesting it. It could be useful in adjusting subplots created using `plt.subplot2grid`.